# Pushing DataBase to PDA results in empty database with RAPI2

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite, rapi

I have a WorkAboutPro 4 and on this i run an application.
This application uses an SQLlite database.

Now i also run a computer program along side it, in here i use RAPI2 to work with my handheld device.
As soon i connect my device a function triggers and it first pulls my database from my handheld to my computer.
I then do some stuff with it and go on to push it back. problem is that the database that returns is always 0kb and has no data, not even tables.

```
//Create my Paths
string myDevice = device.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
string deviceFile = myDevice + @"\PPPM\SQL_PPPM.s3db";
string myComputer = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Substring(6);
string localFile = myComputer + @"\SQL_PPPM.s3db";

//Get the Database
RemoteFile.CopyFileFromDevice(device, deviceFile, localFile, true);

//Do Stuff
try
  ....
catch(Exception ex)
  ....

//Push The Database back
RemoteFile.CopyFileToDevice(device, localFile, deviceFile, true);
```

Now first i thought it was beccause i am not able to push a database over the connection. So i tried to pull a full database to my computer. but this works just fine.
Then i went on and placed an empty Txt file on my hadn held. pulled it, added text and pushed it and also this works fine.

So the only thing that goes wrong is when i try i push a full database back to my HandHeld resulting in an 0kb empty database.

Anyone an idea why this is?

Lotus~

Edit: if you know a beter way to detect if a device is connected and push/pull files from a PDA please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i faced the same problem as well.
It most likely has to do with your Sqlite connections still being open.

The thing that worked out best for me was to modify my SqlDataAccess class and start using the 'using'.

Example:

```
using(var connection = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString))
{
   try
   {
      connection.Open();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      throw new Exception(e.Message);
   }
   finally
   {
      connection.Close();
   }     
}
```

For me the same worked with DataAdapters.

Good luck in the future, and remember never throw yourself in a case of Denvercoder9. You should have answered this a long time ago.